# AHK ControlSend

Tags: winapi, autohotkey

I haven't really dealt much with AHK but I saw a script that manages to send keystrokes to a window and the Window interprets the keystokes and displays them accordingly. The script used a function called ControlSend. And I was curious as to what this function actually does underneath in the Win32 API. The closest function I could assume it uses would be SendMessage/PostMessag; However, when I actually tested PostMessage/SendMessage to the window using WM_KEYDOWN as the message, the window could not interpret it. So this isn't really a coding question but more of which functions does ControlSend in AHK actually rely on in the Win32 API? It's not simulating the keyboard with keybd_event or SendInput either because it manages to send keystrokes even when the process window is in the background and unfocused. I have tried searching this up but no explanation.

This was the AHK script

```
Loop{

sendKey("a")
}


F1::
if (mypid == 0){
    WinGet, var, PID, A
    mypid = %var%
    MsgBox, Found client %mypid%
}



sendKey(key)
{
global mypid
WinClose
ControlSend,,{%key%}, ahk_pid %mypid%
}
```

Comment: Straight from the [tag:autohotkey] tag info: *"AutoHotkey (AHK) is a free, **open-source** macro-creation and automation software for Microsoft Windows \[...\]"*. If you need an answer to your question, you know [where to look](https://github.com/AutoHotkey/AutoHotkey).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AutoHotkey is open source, and you can view the underlying C++ code directly on [Lexikos' GitHub](https://github.com/Lexikos/AutoHotkey_L).

[Here](https://github.com/Lexikos/AutoHotkey_L/blob/90b5c2ac3208c38b9488a72fc3e6e4f9cf20b276/source/keyboard_mouse.cpp#L135) is the function in question you'll want to look at.
The `aTargetWindow` HWND will be non-null if you're control sending.
All kinds of checks and magic is done in there, but in the end, you'll more often than not arrive at [this](https://github.com/Lexikos/AutoHotkey_L/blob/90b5c2ac3208c38b9488a72fc3e6e4f9cf20b276/source/keyboard_mouse.cpp#L1564) function, where the key is *sent* by posting a `WM_KEYDOWN` and `WM_KEYUP` message to the target window.
In some special cases (if the the key doesn't seem to have a VK or SC), it is sent by posting a `WM_CHAR` message.

This is what I could tell by taking a quick look at the source, but as said, there's a lot in there. I'd recommend taking a look yourself an reading through those very helpful comments it has a lot of

Comment: @nin: We don't know, what you have done, so there's nothing we can do to tell you, where things went wrong. However, we can preemptively state: [You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513). Whatever the problem you are trying to solve, this is not a solution. That's something we keep telling developers every single day. I'm not sure what it takes to drive that one home.

Comment: @nin: That's a workaround in case the real solution doesn't work for the envisioned target application. The real solution is to use [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32). Take special note that [AttachThreadInput is like taking two threads and pooling their money into a joint bank account, where both parties need to be present in order to withdraw any money](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130619-00/?p=4043).