# copy & paste command to Powershell

Tags: python, powershell, delphi, delphi-7

Can somebody let me know if possible to copy and paste a command from a TEdit object in Delphi to a current PowerShell window?  I had an input field (Edit1) where if I enter a command and click to a button it will copy and paste to a currently opened PowerShell window.

Comment: Yes, you can do this. See [the answer here in the AutoIT forum](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/159050-autoit-and-delphi-apps/). It's not trivial at all to send keys / text to another window, see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60930110/ahk-controlsend).

Comment: At SO, there is no *second question*. If you have one, use the *Ask Question* button to create a new post. And before you ask that question, do some searching here to see if the question has been asked before.